# Select all text only on first click

Tags: javascript, dojo

I'm using Dojo 1.6 and want to select all the text of a textbox only at the first click. I know I can use `dojo.byId("id").select();` to select the whole text, but the problem is that you can't make a subselection of text anymore. I've provided a small code example to show the problem.

```
require(["dojo/parser", "dijit/form/TextBox"]);

require(["dojo/query", "dojo/on",  "dojo/domReady!"], function(query, on) {
    query("#firstname").on("click", function(evt) {
        // this will not work because I want to select 1 or more characters
        if (!dojo.byId("firstname").select())
           dojo.byId("firstname").select();
    });
});
```

And the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3CLz9/

So the main problem is that I can't determine if one or more characters are selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `dojo/on` module's [`once()`](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/on.html#once) function. But I don't think that this is what you want. I suppose you want to select the text each time the input field gains **focus**. If you want this, you should be using the `onFocus` event, (so replace the `"click"` by `"focus"`).

The only problem now is that after you select the text, the default event will move your cursor to the selected position and unselect your text (you will see it blink). To solve that you should also bind an `mouseup` event handler that cancels when you just gained focus. For example:

```js
query("#firstname").on("focus", function(evt) {
    this.select();
    on.once(this, "mouseup", function(evt) {
       evt.preventDefault(); 
    });
});
```

I also updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3CLz9/4/).

---

I just noticed that you're actually using a `dijit/form/TextBox` widget (didn't work on your JSFiddle so that's why I didn't notice it), but you can easily do this with the `selectOnClick` property. Add it to your `data-dojo-props` and it will work.

For example:

```html
<input type="text" name="firstname" value="testing testing"
    data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TextBox"
    data-dojo-props="trim:true, propercase:true, selectOnClick: true" id="firstname" />
```

Here is [your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3CLz9/5/) (with a working textbox widget). If you want to do the same thing for Dojo versions below 1.7, you can do that like described in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3CLz9/6/).

Comment: I've accepted the answer because it works on the Fiddle. That was were I was looking for, but I mentioned the wrong Dojo version(I was confused because I'm updating Dojo from 1.6 to 1.7(also an IBM/EGL developer hehe), but this was still v1.6 for production. I've edited the question.

Comment: Are you trying to do this on a normal DOM node or on a widget? Because I just noticed you're using a `dijit/form/TextBox` which has a property called `selectOnClick` that does this for you. In your fiddle however your textbox widget is not working. I solved it (look at my updated answer).

Comment: I'm using the textbox widget. The fiddle is just a very basic example. The code we are using is migrated from VAG(java) and we converted eg. a JTextField to javascript(extends the Dojo TextField and a lot of other (custom) widgets). We have build everything programmatically so I have added the `selectOnClick` to the constructor(the application is to big to add it declarative(over 1GB of JS). The only problem is that I've to test everything over again because it the TextField depends on a lot of other widgets. For now, it works excepts on the datagrid but I will take a look at that tomorrow.

Comment: All the problems are solved! Thanks for your help! It's appreciated. Have a nice day. Guy